# fetching data for the second time increments my long variable by 1, causing it not possible to reload data more than once

Tags: android, fetch, long-integer

I have a few data fetching methods that call each other in order to fetch data according to the previous data fetched.

My issue is that I am holding a long variable called 'allContestsCounterIndex' which is incremented only at 2 certain places and for some reason after fetching the data for the first time, when clicking again to try to fetch for the second time the value of it starts with 1, meaning I can't continue because it makes the logic stuck.

here are the functions I am using -

```
private void updateContestCallCounter(long childrenCount) {
    allContestsCounterIndex++;
    if (allContestsCounterIndex == (childrenCount - 1)) { // at this point at the second time this variable starts with a value of 1 instead of 0
      fetchWinnersFromOurValidContests();
    }
  }
```

```
private void fetchAllEndedStatusContests(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
      // For some reason, we've reached this point with no dataSnapShot
      Timber.d("dataSnapShot doesnt exists");
      return;
    }

    long timeInSeconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    mEndedContests = new ArrayList<>();

    long childrenCount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

    for (DataSnapshot status : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

      //fetching the status key for deeper querys inside the db

      final String key = status.getKey();

      checkIfContestEnded(timeInSeconds, key, new OnContestStateReceived() {
        @Override
        public void contestHasEnded() {
          mEndedContests.add(key);
          updateContestCallCounter(childrenCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void contestStillScheduled() {
          updateContestCallCounter(childrenCount);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: The most obvious reason is multithread field access which causes issues. Does you code run in a single thread?

Answer (score 0):

You should set all of your counters to 0 once you have finished re-fetching the data.